# BitSet to and from integer/long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitset

If I have an integer that I'd like to perform bit manipulation on, how can I load it into a `java.util.BitSet`?  How can I convert it back to an int or long?  I'm not so concerned about the size of the `BitSet` -- it will always be 32 or 64 bits long.  I'd just like to use the `set()`, `clear()`, `nextSetBit()`, and `nextClearBit()` methods rather than bitwise operators, but I can't find an easy way to initialize a bit set with a numeric type.

Comment: Personally, I'd say raw bit manipulation is the way to go here. It really isn't that complicated, and as you say I don't see a simple way to get an int or long into a BitSet.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The following code creates a bit set from a long value and vice versa:

```
public class Bits {

  public static BitSet convert(long value) {
    BitSet bits = new BitSet();
    int index = 0;
    while (value != 0L) {
      if (value % 2L != 0) {
        bits.set(index);
      }
      ++index;
      value = value >>> 1;
    }
    return bits;
  }

  public static long convert(BitSet bits) {
    long value = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); ++i) {
      value += bits.get(i) ? (1L << i) : 0L;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

EDITED: Now both directions, @leftbrain: of cause, you are right

Comment: FYI, this is creating a bitset in little-endian order

Comment: You should really use `BitSet.nextSetBit()` for `BitSet -> long`.

Answer (score 49):

Add to finnw answer: there are also [`BitSet.valueOf(long[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf-long:A-) and [`BitSet.toLongArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toLongArray--). So:

```
int n = 12345;
BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{n});
long l = bs.toLongArray()[0];
```

Comment: If the bitset has no "1", bs.toLongArray()[0] will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception!

Answer (score 20):

Java 7 has `BitSet.valueOf(byte[])` and `BitSet.toByteArray()`

If you are stuck with Java 6 or earlier, you can use `BigInteger` if it is not likely to be a performance bottleneck - it has `getLowestSetBit`, `setBit` and `clearBit` methods (the last two will create a new `BigInteger` instead of modifying in-place.)

Answer (score 5):

To get a `long` back from a **small** `BitSet` in a *'streamy'* way:

```
long l = bitSet.stream()
        .takeWhile(i -> i < Long.SIZE)
        .mapToLong(i -> 1L << i)
        .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a | b);
```

Vice-versa:

```
BitSet bitSet = IntStream.range(0, Long.SIZE - 1)
        .filter(i -> 0 != (l & 1L << i))
        .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or);
```

N.B.: Using `BitSet::valueOf` and `BitSet::toLongArray` is of course easier.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much straight from the documentation of nextSetBit

```
value=0;
for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
 value += (1 << i)
 }
```

Comment: This will fail for a BitSet larger than 32 or 64 bits, in such a case you'll need to handle an `int[]` or `long[]` at the output. But OP explicitly doesn't care, so fair enough. Just a few minor glitches: in case of a long you should `1L << i`, to prevent overflow, and an OR like `value |= 1L << i` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin those extensions can be used.

BitSet to Int extension:

```
fun BitSet.toInt() =
    toLongArray()
        .getOrNull(0)
        ?.toInt()
        ?: 0
```

Int to BitSet extension:

```
fun Int.toBitSet(size: Int): BitSet {
    val byteArray = byteArrayOf(toByte())

    return BitSet.valueOf(
        if (byteArray.size == size) byteArray
        else byteArray.copyOf(size))
}
```

Usage example:

```
val intValue = 1

val bitSetValue = intValue.toBitSet(size = 2)
println("bitSetValue: $bitSetValue")

val firstValue = bitSetValue.get(0)
println("firstValue: $firstValue")

val secondValue = bitSetValue.get(1)
println("secondValue: $secondValue")

bitSetValue.set(0, true)
bitSetValue.set(1, false)
println("bitSetValue: $bitSetValue")

val newIntValue = bitSetValue.toInt()
println("newIntValue: $newIntValue")
```

Answer (score -3):

Isn't the `public void set(int bit)` method what your looking for?

Comment: That sets one single bit with the index you provide.  I'd like to set each bit that's set in the integer.