# Convert a byte or int to bitset

Tags: java, type-conversion, bitarray

I have the following:

```
int num=Integer.parseInt(lineArray[0]);
byte numBit= num & 0xFF;
```

Is there any very simple way to convert `numBit` to a bit array? Or even better, is there a way to bypass the byte conversion of the int and go straigh from `num` to a bit array?

Thanks

Comment: I guess this will for in your case too...  
[Stackoverflow - Bitset to and from Integer Long][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473597/bitset-to-and-from-integer-long

Comment: Do you mean `boolean[]` or `BitSet`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf(byte[])), try:

```
final byte b = ...;
final BitSet set = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] { b });
```

If you want a `boolean[]`,

```
static boolean[] bits(byte b) {
  int n = 8;
  final boolean[] set = new boolean[n];
  while (--n >= 0) {
    set[n] = (b & 0x80) != 0;
    b <<= 1;
  }
  return set;
}
```

or, equivalently,

```
static boolean[] bits(final byte b) {
  return new boolean[] {
    (b &    1) != 0,
    (b &    2) != 0,
    (b &    4) != 0,
    (b &    8) != 0,
    (b & 0x10) != 0,
    (b & 0x20) != 0,
    (b & 0x40) != 0,
    (b & 0x80) != 0
  };
}
```

Comment: I came across this answer and wanted to note that the `BitSet.valueOf()` methods are only in Java 7 and later. The question didn't specify a Java version, but if you are in Java 6, you should be able to take one of the approaches to create a boolean[] to populate a BitSet object.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `set[n] = (b & 0x80) != 0;` in your 2nd snippet?
And you need to post-increment in your while loop: `while (n-- > 0)`. Otherwise you're skipping bit 0.

Answer (score 5):

Java 7 has BitSet.valueOf(long[]) and BitSet.toLongArray()

```
int n = 12345;
BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{n});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

`char[] bits = Integer.toBinaryString(num).toCharArray();` to get the underlying bit string as a `char[]`

E.g.

```
public BitSet getBitSet(int num){
    char[] bits = Integer.toBinaryString(num).toCharArray();  
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(bits.length);  
    for(int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++){  
        if(bits[i] == '1'){
            bitSet.set(i, true);
        }
        else{
            bitSet.set(i, false);
        }                
    }
    return bitSet;
}
```

You could create `boolean []` array also this way.

Comment: You're doing double work here -- `toBinaryString()` iterates over the bits too. You'd be better of with looping while `i < Integer.SIZE` and a direct bit test `0 < (num & 1 << i)`. Not to mention that bits in a fresh `BitSet` are pre-set to `false`. Simply put, your code is both verbose and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I came about this thread because Android added the `BitSet.valueOf()`as late as in API 19.
I used oldrinb's 2nd snippet of the accepted answer but had to modify it because it had some errors. Additionally I modified it to return a BitSet, but it shouldn't be a problem to change it to boolean[]. See my comment to his reply.

This is the modification that now runs successfully:

```
public static BitSet toBitSet(byte b) {
    int n = 8;
    final BitSet set = new BitSet(n);
    while (n-- > 0) {
        boolean isSet = (b & 0x80) != 0;
        set.set(n, isSet);
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an excercise in using **streams** (J8+):

```
// J7+
BitSet bitSet(final long... nums) {
    return BitSet.valueOf(nums);
}

// J8+
final IntStream bitsSet = bitSet(num).stream();

// vice-versa
BitSet bitSet(final IntStream bitsSet) {
    return bitsSet.collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or);
}

// without BitSet
IntStream bitsSet(final long... nums) {
    return IntStream.range(0, nums.length)
            .flatMap(n -> IntStream.range(0, Long.SIZE - 1)
                    .filter(i -> 0 != (nums[n] & 1L << i))
                    .map(i -> i + n * Long.SIZE));
}
```