# How to check if a single bit in a given bit is 1 or 0?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

How do I check if a number in bit number is one or zero?
For example:
Number given: 0b00001101
Position of bit index 0 = true
Position of bit index 1 = false

I’m stuck on determining the position of the bit.

Comment: … you’re stuck determining the *position* of a bit? Or its value? What *exactly* is your input, what is your desired output?

Comment: `java.util.BitSet bSet = BitSet .valueOf(new byte[]{ your bytes,...}); bSet.get(0);bSet.get(1);//...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820554/592355

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check if a given position, say `n`, of the binary representation of the number is 0 is to shift the number `n` times and check the last digit shifted. In example

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkPosition(Byte.parseByte(String.valueOf(3)),1));
    }
    // Return true if the given position is 0, false otherwise
    public static boolean checkPosition(Byte b, int position)    {
        return ((b.byteValue() >> position) & 1) == 0;
    }
}
// Output: false
```

Comment: You should use `& 1` rather than `% 2` here.

Answer (score 3):

If you understand how numbers are represented in binary, the easiest way is to use the bitwise **and** operator against the number represented by the bit, and compare the result to the number. For any number, starting on the right, the individual bits represent the numbers 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc for bits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

```
int number = 9;

boolean isBitOneOn = (number & 1) == 1;
boolean isBitTwoOn = (number & 2) == 2;
boolean isBitThreeOn = (number & 4) == 4;
boolean isBitFourOn = (number & 8) == 8;
boolean isBitFiveOn = (number & 16) == 16;
```

In this example the number 9 is represented in binary as 00001001; the bits representing 8 and 1 are on.