# How to set/unset a bit at specific position of a long?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How to set/unset a bit at specific position of a long in Java ?

For example,

```
long l = 0b001100L ; // bit representation
```

I want to set bit at position 2 and unset bit at position 3 thus corresponding long will be,

```
long l = 0b001010L ; // bit representation
```

Can anybody help me how to do that ?

Comment: I assume using a BitSet is not an option.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To set a bit, use:

```
x |= 0b1; // set LSB bit
x |= 0b10; // set 2nd bit from LSB
```

to erase a bit use:

```
x &= ~0b1; // unset LSB bit (if set)
x &= ~0b10; // unset 2nd bit from LSB
```

to toggle a bit use:

```
x ^= 0b1;
```

Notice I use 0b?. You can also use any integer, eg:

```
x |= 4; // sets 3rd bit
x |= 0x4; // sets 3rd bit
x |= 0x10; // sets 9th bit
```

However, it makes it harder to know which bit is being changed.

Using binary allows you to see which exact bits will be set/erased/toggled.

To dynamically set at bit, use:

```
x |= (1 << y); // set the yth bit from the LSB
```

`(1 << y)` shifts the ...001 y places left, so you can move the set bit y places.

You can also set multiple bits at once:

```
x |= (1 << y) | (1 << z); // set the yth and zth bit from the LSB
```

Or to unset:

```
x &= ~((1 << y) | (1 << z)); // unset yth and zth bit
```

Or to toggle:

```
x ^= (1 << y) | (1 << z); // toggle yth and zth bit
```

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I want it to be dynamic means pass position as an argument, not for fixed value.

Comment: Worth to mention how to check bit: right shift it and AND
`bit = (x >> y) & 1`

Answer (score 10):

The least significant bit (lsb) is usually referred to as bit 0, so your 'position 2' is really 'bit 1'.

```
long x = 0b001100;  // x now = 0b001100
x |= (1<<1);        // x now = 0b001110 (bit 1 set)
x &= ~(1<<2);       // x now = 0b001010 (bit 2 cleared)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would choose [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for this...

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Long value = 12L;
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(value));
        System.out.println(b.toString(2) + " " + value);
        b = b.setBit(1);
        b = b.clearBit(2);
        value = Long.valueOf(b.toString());
        System.out.println(b.toString(2) + " " + value);
    }
}
```

and here is the output:

```
1100 12
1010 10
```

Comment: Don't use BigInteger. It was not designed for manipulating bits (slow?!?). If you want an arbitrarily length bit container, use bitsets.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the class java.util.BitSet that do the job for you.

To set : `myByte.set(bit);`
To reset : `myByte.clear(bit);`
To fill with a bool : `myByte.set(bit, b);`
To get the bool : `b = myByte.get(bit);`

Answer (score -1):

- Convert long to a bitset
- Set the bit you need to
- Convert bitset back to long

See this post [BitSet to and from integer/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473597/bitset-to-and-from-integer-long) for methods to convert long to bitset and vice versa

Comment: Using bitsets can work, but I don't recommend converting back and forth just for bit manipulation. Decide if you want to use long or bitset, and stick with it.