# Set particular Bit in Java long value

Tags: java, hex, bit-manipulation, byte, bitwise-operators

I have one long value and Set Particular bit by converting hexadecimal value.

```
long l = 4;

long output; //output is 84 if i want set 7th bit (1000 0100)
```

same way is long is 7 then output is 87 so how to set particular bit inside long value.

Requirement:

I have to send one byte to server by proper formatting.

Client gives following thing.
1. Whether 7th bit set or not set.
2. One integer value (like 4,5,6,7 etc.)
Now I have generate string or decimal (2H) that format as client parameter.

Comment: Is your question how to set a particular bit, or how to get the value in hexadecimal? You don't have to convert to hexadecimal to set a particular bit.

Comment: I know that how to get hexadecimal from long (Long.toHexString(intValue)) but now I want to set particular bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set/unset a bit at specific position of a long in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015598/how-to-set-unset-a-bit-at-specific-position-of-a-long-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a bitwise or with the value of the bit.

The value of the bit you can find by shifting `1L` the correct number of bits to the left. (Don't forget the `L`, without that you're shifting the `int` 1.)

Bitwise or can be done with the `|` operator in Java.

So the code becomes:

```
long output = l | (1L << 7);
```