# Monodroid: How to set the AllowKeyManagement property of a WifiConfiguration

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, wifi

I must be missing something here but I am trying to set the `AllowedKeyManagement` property of a WifiConfiguration like so:

```
config.AllowedKeyManagement = WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.None;
```

However, `AllowedKeyManagement` is of type BitSet and there's no conversion from `KeyManagementType`.  Also tried `Android.Net.Wifi.KeyManagementType.None` which obviously results in the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after an email discussion with Xamarin you cannot simply assign the enum values to AllowedKeyManagement and the same applies to AllowedGroupCipher (or indeed anything value of type BitSet). The enum has to be converted to a BitSet and there is an example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2473719/1555582

I've not tested this yet but if the conversion does not work then I suggest this would result in a different question being posed.

Comment: So now after I pushed them a little further it now appears they made a slight error in the answer they gave. You should be able to do config.AllowedGroupCiphers.Set((int)KeyManagementType.None); .  Again, I've not tested it yet but this would appear to be the right way to go for now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is and old question, but I found how to do it.

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration
{
    Ssid = ssid,
    PreSharedKey = password
};        

wifiConfiguration.AllowedKeyManagement.Set((int)KeyManagementType.WpaPsk);            
wifiConfiguration.AllowedAuthAlgorithms.Set((int)AuthAlgorithmType.Open);
```

Adapted from: [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18373/connect-to-a-specified-wifi)