# How to input an integer's binary expression into a bitSet in java

Tags: java, binary, bitset

How to input an integer's binary expression into a bitSet in java?

say `a = 15` I want put `1111` into a bitSet,

is there a function for this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473597/bitset-to-and-from-integer-long

Comment: Note that one of the later answers to the question @slaadvak references calls attention to "BitSet.valueOf(long[]) and BitSet.toLongArray()".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BitSet` has a static [`valueOf(long[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf%28long%5B%5D%29) method which

> Returns a new bit set containing all the bits in the given long array.

So an array with one long will have 64 bits, an array with two longs will have 128 bits, etc.

If you only need to get a `BitSet` from a single `int` value, use it like so

```
Integer value = 42;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { value });
System.out.println(bitSet);
```

It prints

```
101010
{1, 3, 5}
```

In other words, from the right to left in the representation above, the 2nd, 4th, and 6th bit are set.

Comment: @user3495562 I don't know the internals. That is just a `String` representation indicating the indices of the bits which are set.

Answer (score 1):

In java you can do this! = )

```
    int value = 10; //0b1010
    String bits = Integer.toBinaryString(value); //1010
    BitSet bs = new BitSet(bits.length());
```

Then add the result to the bitset = )

```
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i++) {
        if (bits.charAt(i) == '1') {
            bs.set(i);
        } else {
            bs.clear(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(bs); //{0, 2} so 0th index and 2nd index are set.
```

Comment: Thanks then how to put this string into a bitSet?

Comment: How to put it in bitSet, by for loop?

Comment: that's one way! @user3495562 = )

for (int i =0 ; i < string.length ; i++) { if string[i] == 1; bitset.clear(i)
else bitset.set(i)

Comment: @user3495562 yooo u gotta give me credit for the right answer = ) hit the checkmark please! ;D

Comment: How to give you credit, I am new, I just say I accept your answer, does that help?

Comment: click on the checkmark! below the upvote buttons! damn, you gave the other dude the credit! he didn't even answer your question. lol

Comment: COnversely, How to invert a binary string to interger?

Comment: int base = 2;
for (Integer num : new Integer[] {~0, ~1}) {
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(num);            
    Long decimal = Long.parseLong(binaryString, base);
    System.out.println("INPUT=" + binaryString + " decimal=" + decimal.intValue()) ;
}