# How to pick out part of bits from a 8bytes data in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java. I have 8 bytes (or `dlc` bytes ) of data in Java, which looks like this :

```
int dlc = 8;
byte[] myData = new byte[dlc];
```

Then I would like to get the value (start bit is 50, length is 2 bits) from `myData`.

My idea is to convert `myData` to bits, then find the value start from bits 50 and has a length of 2 bits, then convert the bits values to integer, is this method good ? if it's available, then how to do it in java ? if it's not, any ideas to pick out some part of value from bytes array ?

---

Solution :
The solution is provided by @Zoyd

NOTE :  BitSet.valueOf(Bytebuffer) is added from Android API 19! so if you have earlier API level, you cannot use valueOf() method. You can look at [BitSet to and from integer/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473597/bitset-to-and-from-integer-long)

Comment: You should look up bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xing Fei's anwer is fine, but if you need a *general* method, you can make a BitSet from your byte array :

```
final BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(myData);
```

Then, you can write, for example :

```
boolean b = bs.get(50);
```

to obtain the value of bit 50.

Comment: This is only getting one bit value, how to get e.g. 9 bits of value and represent it into a integer ?

Comment: bs.get(50,58) (returns another bitset)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(myData[6] & 0x60) >> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In explanation of Xing Fei: `myData[6]` gives you bits 49 to 56, by AND-ing this with 0x60 (= 01100000) you set bits 49, 52, 53, 54, 55, and 56 to zero. If you shift this 5 bits to the right (>> - Operator) you have your result.