# Packing an array of booleans into an int in Java

Tags: java

I'm not very familiar with all the bit shifting and masks that are involved with the process but I have a vague idea.

I'm looking for a way to pack around 30 booleans into an int or long so I can send the packed data through one data type, rather than sending across 30 separate booleans. Either this if it's possible, or the use of a bit set might help. I was wondering if someone could give me a little insight into how to go about packing the values.

Comment: the most novice technique i would do If the ordering doesn't matter than I would simply append 0 and 1's boolean results to a string and send it over.

Comment: all the answers below dose make sense, however how are you intending to read this data structure of ones and zeros ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BitSet to and from integer/long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473597/bitset-to-and-from-integer-long)

Comment: I'm looking for the most efficient way of doing it and of course for learning purposes as I don't know much about bit manipulation, and yes they need to be ordered and they need unpacking when they are received so the values can be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an `int` (32 bits), you can set, clear, and check the N'th (0-31) bit like this:

```
int bits = 0;

// Set bit n
bits |= 1 << n;

// Clear bit n
bits &= (1 << n) ^ -1;

// Check bit n
if ((bits & 1 << n) != 0) { /*bit was set*/ }
```

So, to convert a `boolean` array into a bitmask:

```
boolean[] bools = /*allocated elsewhere, max. length: 32*/;

int bits = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bools.length; i++)
    if (bools[i])
        bits |= 1 << i;
```

And to convert a bitmask to a `boolean` array:

```
int bits = /*assigned elsewhere*/;

boolean[] bools = new boolean[30]; /*max. length: 32*/
for (int i = 0; i < bools.length; i++)
    if ((bits & 1 << i) != 0)
        bools[i] = true;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the demo. As I'm doing this for learning purposes also, could you please explain the shifting that is going on here? like if ((bits & 1 << i) != 0), I get that it's checking if a certain bit is equal to one, but what does the & 1 << i mean?

Answer (score 3):

A boolean represents a bit of information, 30 booleans represent 30 bits of information. Build an `int` (32 bits), send it, job done.

May not be the best approach, but just to give you an idea

```
    int i=0;
    boolean[]a = {true,false,true,false,false,false,false};
    for(boolean b:a)i=i*2+(b?1:0);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
```

prints

```
    1010000
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes I gathered this, but I was more concerned about the packing/unpacking or the "building" aspect

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of booleans `Boolean b[30]` you can declare an `int x = 0` and iterate through b and for every iteration do `x = x*2 // move to next bit` and `x = x+1 // if b is true`

```
    Boolean b[30];  // assign values to array...
    int x = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++){
        if (b[i] == true ){
            x = x+1;
        }
        x = x*2;
    }
```

Now, you can go over x and check the 30 bits, after the first. When a bit equals 1 it means the corresponding boolean was true. The first bit was initilized as 1, so this would work, even if the first bool is false

Comment: That works. Would this work for the unpacking too as I've got to read the data back and verify it when it reaches the server

Comment: your result int would be like: 1 <<- prefix (don't use) and then 30 bits that are "1" for true and "0" for false. divide the int by 2 and check it LSB using x & 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    boolean b[] = new boolean[32];
    b[2] = true;
    b[31] = true;
    int m = 0x01;
    int n = 0;
    for(int j = b.length - 1; j >=0; j--) {
        if(b[j]) n |= m;
        m = (m<< 1);
    }
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
    // Output: 100000000000000000000000000001
```

And I guess you can unpack by & instead of |