# How to build an int value with bytes in Java?

Tags: java

My question is about Java int data structure.

If I have a buffer of 4 bytes

`byte[] buffer = {(byte)A, (byte)B, (byte)C, (byte)D};`

How to build a positive and a negative int values using this array and logic operators (`&`, `|`, `<<`, `>>`)?

Say int = 4 and int = 130; and -4 and -130.

Comment: Does it need to be logic operators, or rather bitwise operators?

Comment: When dealing with byte data, you should use hexadecimal notation instead of decimal. With that in mind, show four byte values for your array and what the resulting `int` value should be **in hex**.

Comment: Probably, you mean bitwise operator.

Comment: You could use a `BitSet` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473597/bitset-to-and-from-integer-long

Comment: Bitwise and logic.. not any function from lib

Comment: Let's assume you have `byte[] buffer = { (byte) 1, (byte) -2, (byte) 3, (byte) -4 };`. What is the expected value out pf this array?

Comment: are these bytes little endian or big?

Comment: Java format. Big? )

Comment: @Rubik endianness is not property of programming language per se, rather cpu, or the way integer was originally packed into byte array, in java you can pack them both ways

Comment: Déjà vu: [Negative Int value from Big Endian to Small](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60329073/85421)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to construct 32 bit value from four 8 bit values you need to know [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

if we assume that high bits are stored into first byte, then you can do:

```
int v = 0;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    v = (v<<8) | (buffer[i]&0xff);
```

if high bits are stored in last byte, then you need to reverse loop

```
int v = 0;
for (int i=3; i>=0; i--)
    v = (v<<8) | (buffer[i]&0xff);
```

Comment: Assume, you've received the buffer from Windows [130, 0, 0, 0].. as int = 130. now, please, give me the code that will rebuild the same value from that buffer into new int and with the same value = 130.

Comment: @Rubik just reverse the loop

Comment: Pls, do it with byte[] buffer = [(byte)130, (byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)0]; and get the result = 130 in the value

Comment: @Rubik just did it and 2nd loop prints 130

Comment: Gotya!! Thank you!! Tell me why do you add & 0xff ?

Comment: @Rubik java performs byte to int conversion preserving sign, so byte value `0x80` will be casted to int as `0xff ff ff 80`, to trim these sign bit extension we need to & with 0xff

Comment: What if it is negative value in buffer?

Comment: @Rubik negative values have sign bit set, which is extended during cast and this is why we're doing &0xff

Comment: PLEASE, ADD YOUR LAST PHRASE TO YOUR ANSWER

Comment: I tried it with negative value and it worked. Then Why in Windows they add 255, so that -130 is translated into { 126, 255, 255, 255 ) but not in {130, 0, 0, 1 } where 1 is negative sign

Comment: @Rubik this happens because of sign extension and the way negative numbers are represented

Comment: thank you, my question was about 0xff, i tried all and the value was wrong, and it made me stuck.